# How many HTML error pages should I make?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-codes

I am currently developing my website and have added some custom error pages, namely for HTTP 404 and 500. Obviously there are many more error codes than that, but these two are the most common.

What I am wondering is whether there is any rule of thumb for how many you create. Most websites have custom error pages (especially for these two errors), but some have it for others as well. Just how many error pages should I make?

Comment: If they all use the same template but still tell you which error it is, that should be sufficient, no?

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule of thumb and there are so many different error codes that creating a custom page for each of them would be overkilling.

Check the different error codes here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318380

If you want completeness, I recommend you to go to the Error Pages feature configuration in IIS, for example, and check the ones in there and it will be very easy for you to decide whether you want a custom message or not.

401
403
404
405
406
412
500
501
502

My suggestion, and again it is based on you wanting completeness of customization, would go with those. Otherwise, just stick with the defaults and the two you have already customized.

Hope it helps.